# apt-get remove removes unexpected packages

Tags: apt

I'm confused as to why apt-get behaves like this?
I'm trying to uninstall vlc for example. Here is what it says should be removed.

```
nope@turtle:~> sudo apt-get remove vlc
[sudo] password for nope: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  catdoc dvdauthor dvgrab genisoimage kded5 kdenlive-data kinit ktorrent-data libavcodec-ffmpeg56
  libavformat-ffmpeg56 libavresample-ffmpeg2 libavutil-ffmpeg54 libdbusmenu-qt5-2 libepub0 libgif4
  libgtkglext1 libjasper1 libkactivities-bin libkactivities-models1 libkf5archive5 libkf5attica5
  libkf5auth-data libkf5auth5 libkf5bookmarks-data libkf5bookmarks5 libkf5codecs-data libkf5codecs5
  libkf5completion-data libkf5completion5 libkf5config-bin libkf5config-data libkf5configcore5
  libkf5configgui5 libkf5configwidgets-data libkf5configwidgets5 libkf5coreaddons-data libkf5coreaddons5
  libkf5crash5 libkf5dbusaddons-bin libkf5dbusaddons-data libkf5dbusaddons5 libkf5filemetadata-bin
  libkf5filemetadata-data libkf5filemetadata3 libkf5globalaccel-bin libkf5globalaccel-data
  libkf5globalaccel5 libkf5globalaccelprivate5 libkf5gpgmepp5 libkf5guiaddons5 libkf5i18n-data
  libkf5i18n5 libkf5iconthemes-bin libkf5iconthemes-data libkf5iconthemes5 libkf5itemviews-data
  libkf5itemviews5 libkf5jobwidgets-data libkf5jobwidgets5 libkf5kiocore5 libkf5kiofilewidgets5
  libkf5kiontlm5 libkf5kiowidgets5 libkf5newstuff-data libkf5newstuff5 libkf5notifications-data
  libkf5notifyconfig-data libkf5plotting5 libkf5service-bin libkf5service-data libkf5service5
  libkf5solid5 libkf5solid5-data libkf5sonnet5-data libkf5sonnetcore5 libkf5sonnetui5
  libkf5textwidgets-data libkf5textwidgets5 libkf5wallet-data libkf5widgetsaddons-data
  libkf5widgetsaddons5 libkf5windowsystem-data libkf5windowsystem5 libkf5xmlgui-bin libkf5xmlgui-data
  libkf5xmlgui5 libktorrent-l10n libktorrent5 libnepomukcore4 libopenjpeg5 libopenjpeg5:i386
  libphonon4qt5-4 libpodofo0.9.3 libpolkit-qt5-1-1 libpoppler-qt5-1 libpoppler57 libpostproc-ffmpeg53
  libquicktime2 libquvi-scripts libquvi7 libsctp1 libswresample-ffmpeg1 libswscale-ffmpeg3
  libswscale4:i386 libsyndication4 libtrio2 libwebrtc-audio-processing-0 libxt-dev
  linux-headers-4.5.0-1-amd64 linux-headers-4.5.0-1-common linux-image-4.5.0-1-amd64
  linux-image-4.5.0-2-amd64-dbg mplayer2 nepomuk-core-data qml-module-qtquick-controls
  qml-module-qtquick-layouts qml-module-qtquick-window2 qml-module-qtquick2 sonnet-plugins xfce4-volumed
  xscreensaver xscreensaver-data
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  kde-runtime kdenlive kio kmplayer ktorrent libkf5notifications5 libkf5notifyconfig5 libkf5wallet-bin
  libkf5wallet5 libkwalletbackend5-5 phonon phonon-backend-vlc phonon4qt5 phonon4qt5-backend-vlc vlc
  vlc-plugin-vlsub
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 16 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 49.0 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

But I don't want all of those to be removed?

Also the list of stuff that it says "are no longer required". I know that I still use some of those applications. Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: `aptitude why-not` can sometimes tell you why a package is about to be removed....but only from the current state, not from some hypothetical future state where you might `apt-get remove` something it depends on. or is recommended by. unfortunately, that proviso makes it far less useful than it could be.  BTW, "No longer required" has absolutely nothing to do with whether you use a program or not...it's entirely about whether a package was manually or automatically installed and if auto, then it's "no longer required" if you remove the package(s) that caused it to be auto-installed.

Comment: for example, if you `apt-get install foo` and `foo` depends on `libfoo` then `apt-get` will auto-install `libfoo`.  If you later `apt-get remove foo`, it won't automatically remove `libfoo` even if no other package depends on it (you might have some locally compiled software that uses it), it just advises you that libfoo is no longer required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are most likely outdated versions or programs you didn't explicitly install.

Since it blocks you from removing `vlc` as you requested, nothing would stop you from installing those you need after.  It is usually very safe to say `yes` there.

Comment: Okay, but some of those i did install myself such as mplayer2, kdenlive, etc. and i still actively use these. But this shouldn't be something apt should decide, right?

Comment: That would mean that they got installed when you installed `vlc` in the first place.  You should indeed reinstall those that you need.  If you do so before removing `vlc`, then `yum` will not list them anymore.

Comment: Okay, so i removed vlc, did an apt-get autoremove, and had a clean list according to apt-get. Then i installed kdenlive and mplayer again and the list is back saying that they are not required. I'm just confused about why it says that it's not required when i explicitly installed it.

Comment: What do you mean?  Show the command you ran that told you they were not required.

Comment: I ran the same command "sudo apt-get remove vlc" and that's when it told me that kdenlive and mplayer are not required

Comment: Didn't you already remove it in your comment 13 minutes ago?

Comment: yes, i installed it again because i was curious as to why vlc and mplayer were tied together though

Comment: While you're testing that, I would suggest going through with the `vlc` removal and check if `kdenlive` is still working.

Comment: I removed vlc and i checked whether kdenlive and mplayer were still installed. They were not. I had to reinstall them

Comment: That is pretty weird.

Comment: I agree..i guess this is a bug and i should report it to the apt-get team. Thanks though, Julie!

Comment: if you check the dependencies/recommendations for vlc and mplayer (and all subsequent dependencies) you'll probably find a dependency chain between the two.

Comment: Note that this broke so many dependencies across many programs which i can't fix by myself. I might have to purge everything and start over clean

Comment: If you just reinstall `vlc`, doesn't it solve the issues?

Comment: no, it doesn't :(

Comment: and apparantly, it had deleted dependencies which i have compiled and installed myself from github. This is not what apt should have ever been tracking..

Comment: That is actually your fault and not related to the functionality of `aptitude`.

Comment: Okay, could i ask why? I'm just confused..

Comment: There is no way for the package managers to take into account any change you did yourself without using their tools.  When you do something like that, you should at the very least make exceptions for all packages that are affected by your installation with commands such as `sudo apt-mark hold <package>`.  This should be used at a strict minimum as it will make your life a living hell as you already noticed.

Comment: oh okay, i didn't know that. Thank you for the clarification :)